# Editing one XML node value in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file similar to this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<page>
<desc><title>user</title><username>user</username> 
<petcount>0</petcount> 
<pagedt><![CDATA[<html><body><p><center><h2>I am amazing.</h2></center>
</p></body></html>]]></pagedt></desc> 
<petlist></petlist><friends></friends><messages><message><user>Admin</user><link>/admin</link>
<note>Welcome to My website!</note></message></messages></page>
```

I am trying to get PHP to only edit the text in `<pagedt>`, and have a textarea that displays the content that is currently in the file, so far, I have the textarea with the contents, running in a form with phpself and via post. Any ideas as to how I can edit just the contents of pagedt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that PHP can read and write the file, all you need is either the [XML parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) or a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) that would match the inner content of `<pagedt>`, like this:

```
$fcontent=file_get_contents("file.xml");
$content=array();
preg_match("/^(.*<pagedt>)(.*)(</pagedt>.*)\$/", $fcontent, $content);
//do your stuff on $content[2], which contains what's between <pagedt> and </pagedt>
file_put_contents("file.xml", $content[1].$content[2].$content[3]);
```

Instead of regular expressions, you can also use [String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) like `strstr`, or combine `strpos` and `substr`. But it's no fun then ;)

Comment: Thank you for this, but when it runs it gives me "Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/kennroo/public_html/newsite/profileedit.php on line 17"

Comment: Remove the $ from preg_match. So preg_match(...) instead of $preg_match(...)

Comment: Ok. i get it now. I figured out a way to extend off of this to do exactly what i want and more. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!

Comment: Glad this could help ;) And indeed, I should have mentionned I hadn't tested this code... Anyway, it was just an example to show how the parsing could be done manually (though I have no idea how heavy this script is compared to PHP's built-in XML parser, or compared to using String functions).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parsing it as XML? I know PHP's DOM library allows you to parse it into an object which you can use to return the pagedt tag and the text contents from there. Try starting here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php